# Python - List of unique sequences

Tags: python, set

I have a dictionary with elements as lists of certain sequence:

```
a = {'seq1':['5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '6', '7', '8', '9'], 
     'seq2':['9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1'],
     'seq3':['5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
     'seq4':['15', '16', '17'],
     'seq5':['18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23'],
     'seq6':['18', '19', '20', '24', '25', '26']}
```

So there are 6 sequences

What I need to do is:

- To find only unique lists (if two lists contains the same elements (regardless of their order), they are not unique) - say I need to get rid of the second list (the first founded unique list will stay)
- In unique lists I need to find unique subsequences of elements and print
  it

Bounds of unique sequences are found by resemblance of elements order - in the 1st and the 3rd lists the bound ends exactly after element '1', so we get the subsequence ['5','4','3','2','1']

As the result I would like to see elements exactly **in the same order** as it was in the beginning (if it`s possible at all somehow). So I expect this:

```
[['5', '4', '3', '2', '1']['6', '7', '8', '9']['11', '12', '13', '14']['15', '16', '17']['18', '19', '20']['21', '22', '23']['24', '25', '26']]
```

Tried to do it this way:

```
import itertools

unique_sets = []

a = {'seq1':["5","4","3","2","1","6","7","8","9"], 'seq2':["9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1"], 'seq3':["5","4","3","2","1","11","12","13","14"], 'seq4':["15","16","17"], 'seq5':["18","19","20","21","22","23"], 'seq6':["18","19","20","24","25","26"]}

b = []

for seq in a.values():
    b.append(seq)

for seq1, seq2 in itertools.combinations(b,2):                                     #searching for intersections 
    if set(seq1).intersection(set(seq2)) not in unique_sets:
        #if set(seq1).intersection(set(seq2)) == set(seq1):
            #continue
        unique_sets.append(set(seq1).intersection(set(seq2)))
    if set(seq1).difference(set(seq2)) not in unique_sets:
        unique_sets.append(set(seq1).difference(set(seq2)))

for it in unique_sets:
    print(it)
```

I got this which is a little bit different from my expectations:

```
{'9', '5', '2', '3', '7', '1', '4', '8', '6'}
set()
{'5', '2', '3', '1', '4'}
{'9', '8', '6', '7'}
{'5', '2', '14', '3', '1', '11', '12', '4', '13'}
{'17', '16', '15'}
{'19', '20', '18'}
{'23', '21', '22'}
```

Without comment in the code above the result is even worse.

Plus I have the problem with unordered elements in the sets, which I get as the result. Tried to do this with two separate lists:

```
seq1 = set([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
seq2 = set([1,2,3,4,5,10,11,12])
```

and it worked fine - elements didn`t ever change their position in sets. Where is my mistake?

Thanks.

**Updated:** Ok, now I have a little bit more complicated task, where offered alghorithm won`t work

I have this dictionary:

```
precond = {

'seq1':     ["1","2"],
'seq2':     ["3","4","2"],
'seq3':     ["5","4","2"],
'seq4':     ["6","7","4","2"],
'seq5':     ["6","4","7","2"],
'seq6':     ["6","1","8","9","10"],
'seq7':     ["6","1","8","11","9","12","13","14"],
'seq8':     ["6","1","8","11","4","15","13"],
'seq9':     ["6","1","8","16","9","11","4","17","18","2"],
'seq10':    ["6","1","8","19","9","4","16","2"],
}
```

I expect these sequences, containing at least 2 elements:

```
[1, 2], 
[4, 2], 
[6, 7], 
[6, 4, 7, 2], 
[6, 1, 8] 
[9,10], 
[6,1,8,11]
[9,12,13,14]
[4,15,13]
[16,9,11,4,17,18,2]
[19,9,4,16,2]
```

Right now I wrote this code:

```
precond = {

    'seq1':     ["1","2"],
    'seq2':     ["3","4","2"],
    'seq3':     ["5","4","2"],
    'seq4':     ["6","7","4","2"],
    'seq5':     ["6","4","7","2"],
    'seq6':     ["6","1","8","9","10"],
    'seq7':     ["6","1","8","11","9","12","13","14"],
    'seq8':     ["6","1","8","11","4","15","13"],
    'seq9':     ["6","1","8","16","9","11","4","17","18","2"],
    'seq10':    ["6","1","8","19","9","4","16","2"],
}

seq_list = []
result_seq = []
#d = []

for seq in precond.values():
    seq_list.append(seq)

#print(b)

contseq_ind = 0
control_seq = seq_list[contseq_ind]
mainseq_ind = 1
el_ind = 0
#index2 = 0

def compar():
    if control_seq[contseq_ind] != seq_list[mainseq_ind][el_ind]:
        mainseq_ind += 1
        compar()
    else:
        result_seq.append(control_seq[contseq_ind])
        contseq_ind += 1
        el_ind += 1

        if contseq_ind > len(control_seq):
            control_seq = seq_list[contseq_ind + 1]
            compar()
        else:
            compar()


compar()
```

This code is not complete anyway - I created looking for the same elements from the beginning, so I still need to write a code for searching of sequence in the end of two compared elements.

Right now I have a problem with recursion. Immidiately after first recursed call I have this error:

```
if control_seq[contseq_ind] != b[mainseq_ind][el_ind]:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'control_seq' referenced before assignment
```

How can I fix this? Or maybe you have a better idea, than using recursion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Python guarantees no order to the elements of sets. (In fact, the set abstract data type does not impose order on its elements.) With the list of ints (instead of strings), you just got lucky because of how Python hashes integers.

Comment: Also, if you're looking for sequences, simply comparing the intersections of the set-ified lists won't work—you delete information about ordering.

Comment: Sad to hear it. If there any possible way to do this? Actual lists contain exactly string elements unfortunately. Should I compare each element of each list directly?

Comment: What is a sequence here? `5, 4, 3`? `5, 4`? `5`? And what would be the output for `['5', '4', '3', '2'], ['1', '4', '3', '2'], ['5', '4', '3', '1']`?

Comment: Looking at your expected output, why is there a break in the series between the `'1'` and `'6'` of the first two elements of your output `['5', '4', '3', '2', '1'],['6', '7', '8', '9']`.

Comment: 2 Mrt Actually, I wasn t much concrete. I have 6 sequences at the beginning and I need to break it smartly into subsequences and the problem is to find the borders of these subsequences. These borders are defined rather by crossing the same elements in each set (if I try to solve this task via set, of course, which could be a wrong way). In this contest such sequences which you mentioned couldn t appear here, because intersecton() and difference() don`t work like that.

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) `Actually, I [wasn't very] concrete` don't comment comments asking for clarification or additional information: edit your question.

Comment: 2 Mike   Break in this sequence is defined by the resemblance of order of elements ['5', '4', '3', '2', '1'] in the first and the third lists. From this point of view I could get the sequence ['9', '8', '7', '6'] from the second list, but I don t want it, that s why firstly i need a mechanism, which determine the uniqueness of lists (say, if I find two lists with the same elements, I will delete second list to get rid of factual duplications).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you wanted, but it gets the same result:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

a = {'seq1':["5","4","3","2","1","6","7","8","9"],
     'seq2':["9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1"],
     'seq3':["5","4","3","2","1","11","12","13","14"],
     'seq4':["15","16","17"],
     'seq5':["18","19","20","21","22","23"],
     'seq6':["18","19","20","24","25","26"]}

level = 0
counts = OrderedDict()
# go through each value in the list of values to count the number
# of times it is used and indicate which list it belongs to
for elements in a.values():
    for element in elements:
        if element in counts:
            a,b = counts[element]
            counts[element] = a,b+1
        else:
            counts[element] = (level,1)
    level+=1

last = 0
result = []
# now break up the dictionary of unique values into lists according 
# to the count of each value and the level that they existed in 
for k,v in counts.items():
    if v == last:
        result[-1].append(k)
    else:
        result.append([k])
    last = v

print(result)
```

Result:

```
[['5', '4', '3', '2', '1'], 
 ['6', '7', '8', '9'], 
 ['11', '12', '13', '14'], 
 ['15', '16', '17'], 
 ['18', '19', '20'], 
 ['21', '22', '23'], 
 ['24', '25', '26']]
```

Comment: Yep, it's seems so. Thank you so much. Anyway the answer is definetely more complex than I thought.

Comment: Lol, I was thinking that the code in your question was more complex. Let me know if there is anything more I can do.

Comment: Actually now I need to know how Ordered dict() works, but it will be my task already :) Don`t want to close this question yet, because after that I need to try to count the number of lists, containing a certain subsequence. Try to do this tomorrow.

Comment: Hi I updated the task. Unfortunately after that updating your alghorythm doesn't work anymore. I would be grateful if you'd look at it